# finding the keyword in multiple columns and show the text around it

Tags: mysql

If I want to do a search on multiple columns for the keyword abc using like %abc%, how would I show some of the text around that keyword. Similar to what Google does with its search results.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is generally referred to as [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).  You will most likely need to use a separate indexing service like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/).  You can also look at the other questions on SO tagged [full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-search).

Answer (score 0):

There is the LOCATE() function and LIKE/REGEX operators you can use, when a Full Text Search index is not possible.

```
SELECT * FROM table
 WHERE LOCATE("abc",fieldA) 
    OR fieldB LIKE "%abc%"
    OR fieldC REGEX ".*[Aa][bB][Cc].*"
```

By having your data on different columns you may partially defeat the index on the table when using 'OR' logic.

-- J Jorgenson --